Supabase join table query returns null if foreign key is added
So I'm learning Supabase, but I got stuck on a query. I reproduced this docs example: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select, with the example "Query referenced tables through a join table". I added the example data source in the SQL Editor and created those tables.
I tested it with the example query and it gave the expected reponse:
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('users')
  .select(`
    name,
    teams (
      name
    )
  `)

However, when I added a new column (trainer_id, which is a foreign key to the users.id) in the teams table, that same query returns null.
Why does it return null if a foreign key is added? Should I change my query? The goal is to get the exact same response as in the example.

can you add the create table for both tables, it seems that you have the foreign key wrong

So I found the answer, it was because there were two relationships after I added a foreign key in the poules table.
Answer:
const { data, error } = await supabase.from('users').select(`
  name,
  teams!users_teams (
    name
  )
`);

